# How to disable compact braces in IntelliJ idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting, format, settings

I simply want to change the default auto curly braces from shortening, example of this:

```
Public void main()
{

}
```

Instead of:

```
Public void main() {

}
```

Comment: ...... but why?

Comment: Confuses me too much

Comment: I can relate, but unless you plan on never working with anyone else, it's best to adapt to common conventions than to recreate them to suit your preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the `File, Settings...` menu.

In the `Settings` dialog, choose `Editor, Code Style, Java`.

Click on the `Wrapping and Braces` tab.

FInd `Braces placement` and change "end of line" to "Next line".